# Open Am No Hearbeat Detected for connection LDAP

Tags: ldap, openam, opendj

I'm trying to create an openam server and am getting the error after it hangs on the configuring server.Does anyone know why the heartbeat wouldn't be found? Might it have to do with the port that it's looking at or the "openam.example.com/127.0.0.1:50389"?

[Click] [error] handleException: Exception in thread "http-bio-8092-exec-10" Oct 18, 2014 12:01:47 PM org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.HeartBeatConnectionFactory$ConnectionImpl checkForHeartBeat

WARNING: No heartbeat detected for connection'LDAPConnection(/127.0.0.1:2801,openam.example.com/127.0.0.1:50389)'

```
Registering service famSAML2Config.xml...Success.
Registering service famWSSAuthService.xml...Success.
Registering service OAuth2Provider.xml...Success.
Registering service MailServer.xml...Success.
Registering service RestSecurity.xml...Success.
Configuring system....Done
Configuring server instance....Done
```

Answer (score 0):

If web container (Tomcat) is not configured to run with enough memory, the embedded configuration LDAP store on port 50389 may run out of memory and not respond to heartbeat. See [OpenAM Troubleshooting](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/12.0.0/admin-guide/index/chap-troubleshooting.html).